# how to troubleshooting nodejs?

Tags: node.js, request, cgi

I have a weird problem and need to troubleshoot it.

In my web application, I used the request module to get data from database. However, the request function didn't go to the api route setting(all other requests work well). How could I trace it to find out where it is coming from?

The error message I got back is:

```
{
  errors: {
    'confirmed_by.id': {
      message: 'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "ending" at path "confirmed_by.id"',
      name: 'CastError',
      stringValue: '"ending"',
      kind: 'ObjectID',
      value: 'ending',
      path: 'confirmed_by.id',
      reason: [Object],
    },
  },
  _message: 'order validation failed',
  message:
    'order validation failed: confirmed_by.id: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "ending" at path "confirmed_by.id"',
  name: 'ValidationError',
}
```

Does anyone have any idea about this? Thanks in advance!

Richard

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when you are trying to create a `_id` for the mongoose model using `_id: new ObjectId(someVal)`. Here, you must ensure that the `someVal` should be 24 character hexadecimal value. Otherwise, it will raise that error. If say, you have `someVal` as 18 characters then add some static characters like `aabbcc` which is 6 characters more to make it 24 characters and most importantly, all needs to be hexadecimal characters.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem I have is that I don't know where the code is being called and where it comes from. I need to trace it.

Comment: @RichardXu you should check where you have used `confirmed_by.id` and set a value there

Comment: I say it weird because it didn't follow the route settings. I have no idea how the code being executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to debug a node application based on what you need to do or what issues you are having.

If you are on a fairly recent node version (v6.3+), you can always start your app with `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk` which will enable you to inspect your node code using Chrome. More details at https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_advanced_usage. In the case you are in an older version you can try with [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector)

Another very useful tool is a network inspector (is that the right name?) like CharlesProxy; with this, you can configure your node application to proxy any http requests (configuration depends on which library you might be using) and inspect the traffic going between your node app and the rest of the world.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. How to trace which route it is going?

Comment: Once you start your code with --inspect or --inspect-brk you can add break points on your different routes. You can also add some log statements to help you find out.